# Why is this Regex.Match failing?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this little method to look for the 3-digit number in a string and increment it by one. The types of strings I am passing in are like `CP1-P-CP2-004-D` and `MOT03-C-FP04-003`.

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

foreach (char c in alphabet)
{
    m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[" + c + "-]|$)");
}

if (m.Success)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value); i += 1;
    Console.WriteLine(s + " - " + i.ToString("D3"));
}
else { Console.WriteLine(s + " - No success"); }
```

**EDIT:** Initially I just had this; to test out my `Regex.Match` case:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[A-]|$)");
```

And it worked with `CP1PCP2001A` no worries, but when I updated it, and tried `CP1PCP2001C` it returned "No Success", while `CP1PCP2001` works no problem. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: what are the contents of `alphabet`? a-z?

Comment: did you try to match it separately as well?

Comment: I'm highly suspicious of a loop that appears to throw away the results from previous cycles around the loop. What was the *intention* of that `foreach`?

Comment: So now you have `\d{3}(?=[Z-]|$)` regex in the end. Of course it will match `CP1PCP2001` because it is ended with `001` (`$` condition in your regex), but won't match `CP1PCP2001C`, since it doesn't have 3-digit sequence followed by `Z`, dash or end-of-line. Why don't you just use single regex `\d{3}(?=[A-Z-]|$)` without any loop?

Comment: Could you please specify the expected output for CP1PCP2001C? Do you want to match 200, 001, 2001, or fail?

Comment: @Chris the expected output would be `002`. By my understanding the case looks for the first 3 digit number (coming from the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, we're looking for "the first 3 digit number (coming from the right)". Here's a literal implementation:

```
m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

This is more permissive towards unexpected characters than the other answers. You can decide whether that's good or bad for your application.

Comment: will it take into account the character(s) at the end? (`-` and `A`)

Comment: Sorry, take into account in what sense?

Comment: So it won't clash, for example if the number had something like `002-A` on the end. And also (as you can see above) some numbers might end with `CP2001`. I'm assuming that it's counting the first 3 digits it comes across `001` it wont count the `2`

Comment: Clash? I haven't tested this code, but it should simply match the rightmost 3-digit sequence in `s`. In `002-A` it should match `002`. In `CP2001` it should match `001`. In `l--iW@#$%oi98765$%a-sdf-A-A-AAA` it should match `765`.

Comment: Well then. Perfect! Why worry about the excess when there's no need.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[A-Z\-]|$)");
```

`[A-Z]` means that it can be any of the capital letters between A and Z thus eliminating the need for `char[] alphabet`, and the `\-` allows you to add the '-' as a parameter, without causing conflict with the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

re-write the code this way

```
bool matched = false;
foreach (char c in alphabet)
{
    m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[" + c + "-]|$)");

    if (m.Success)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value); i += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(s + " - " + i.ToString("D3"));
        matched=true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!matched)
    Console.WriteLine(s + " - No success");
```

---

a better way would be not to loop and specify the char range to match in regex itself

example

```
    m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[A-Z\-]|$)");

    if (m.Success)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value); i += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(s + " - " + i.ToString("D3"));
    }
    else
       Console.WriteLine(s + " - No success");
```

regex [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/sE8hR9/1)

Comment: ok so your second suggestion works really well. But do you know why this was failing in the first place? I'm assuming it's the format of the string, Because `CP1-P-CP2-001-C` works fine, but `CP1PCP2001C` fails?

Comment: your regex was correct but the reason was loop, because of that the last match in the loop was checked for the condition while ignoring the previous one. i.e. with letter `Z` and since `CP1PCP2001C` does not match with the same as it has the letter `C` so condition evaluates to false. for the same reason you can see in the first solution I have terminated the loop after first successful match. `CP1-P-CP2-001-C` works because it was successfully able to match a `-` after the 3 digits in all of the iterations of the loop.